# How to decode json and set value in json to php available ?

Tags: php, json

i have json `$json` like this

```
{"name":"peter","availability":"available"}
```

i want to decode and set value to php available and `echo` but not any show ?, i use this code

```
<?PHP
                 $decode = json_decode($json, true);
                 $availability = $decode[availability];
                 echo $availability;  
?>
```

where is wrong ?

Comment: I copy/pasted that code and it worked fine. whatever your problem is, it isn't expressed in the question.

Comment: this is my full code that not work

`<?php
$arr = array('name' => peter, 'availability' => available);
$json = json_encode($arr);
$decode = json_decode($json, true);
$availability = $json_decode[availability];
print_r($json);
echo $availability;  
?>`

Comment: You've mistyped a variable name. I've created a community wiki answer to highlight it. Can people reading this question close it as "caused by a typo" since it holds no long term value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use as

```
$availability = $decode["availability"];
```

If you use

```
$availability = $decode[availability];
```

It will raise a notice as

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant availability - assumed 'availability'
```

However your code is correct is should display the value with the above notice unless the `$json` string is not the one you have added.

Your code

```
<?php 
$arr = array('name' => peter, 'availability' => available); 
$json = json_encode($arr); 
$decode = json_decode($json, true); 
$availability = $json_decode[availability]; 
print_r($json); 
echo $availability; 
?>
```

Now this is what you are doing

```
$decode = json_decode($json, true); 
$availability = $json_decode[availability];
```

You are using a different array name `$json_decode` instead of  `$decode`

So the correct way is

```
$arr = array('name' => 'peter', 'availability' => 'available'); 
$json = json_encode($arr); 
$decode = json_decode($json, true); 
$availability = $decode['availability']; //print_r($json); 
echo $availability;
```

Comment: Ahhh you beat me to it!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Using quotes around array keys is good coding style, but doesn't explain why the OP's code isn't working for them.

Answer (score 0):

You supplied your full code in a comment:

```
$decode = json_decode($json, true); 
$availability = $json_decode[availability];
```

`$decode` and `$json_decode` are not the same variable name. Pick one and be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the quotes. It should be

```
$availability = $decode['availability'];
```

And instead of just echoing out an array, you can use pretty print.

Try

```
$json = '{"name":"peter","availability":"available"}';
$decode = json_decode($json, true);
//$availability = $decode['availability'];
echo "<pre>";
print_r($decode);
```